# Формат текущей даты и времени

Tags: javascript

Как получить текущую дату и время в формате: 12:50:12 04.12.2017?

**Формат**

```
hh:MM:ss dd.mm.yyyy
```

**P.S**.Работаю из расширения, из внедренного кода, подключение других скриптов не вариант.

Comment: @Darth вариант из ответа в том вопросе не подходит для меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чем не подходит?

```js
Date.prototype.format = function(format = 'yyyy-mm-dd') {
    const replaces = {
        yyyy: this.getFullYear(),
        mm: ('0'+(this.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        dd: ('0'+this.getDate()).slice(-2),
        hh: ('0'+this.getHours()).slice(-2),
        MM: ('0'+this.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        ss: ('0'+this.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    };
    let result = format;
    for(const replace in replaces){
        result = result.replace(replace,replaces[replace]);
    }
    return result;
};
        
        
console.log((new Date()).format('hh:MM:ss dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

**UP:** однострочка:

```js
const formatDate = date => ('0'+date.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0'+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0'+date.getSeconds()).slice(-2)  + ' ' + ('0'+date.getDate()).slice(-2)  + '.' + ('0'+(date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)  + '.' + date.getFullYear();

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Comment: Не подходить тем что придется во всех скриптах этот код писать, а скриптов много.

Comment: @myvvar ну, можно сделать покороче, конкретно под ваш формат, но смысл будет тот же.. проще никак, js в этом плане инвалид(

Comment: Мне и надо покороче, в одну строчку.

Comment: @myvvar обновил ответ