# Как у казать в поле текущую дату и текущее время?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var date = document.getElementById('one');
var dateObj = new Date();
date.value = dateObj;
```

```html
<input id="one" type="date">
 <input id="two" type="time">
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Формат текущей даты и времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753506/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676806/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-javascript и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768847/javascript-%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8/768866#768866

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var date = document.getElementById('one');
var time = document.getElementById('two');
var dateObj = new Date();
date.value = dateObj.toISOString().slice(0,10)
time.value = dateObj.getHours() + ':' + dateObj.getMinutes();
```

```html
<input id="one" type="date">
<input id="two" type="time">
```

Comment: А что значит .slice(0,10)

Comment: И время то работает то нет.

Comment: @Sinevik
про `slice` - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
про время - то работает то нет так не бывает причина есть всегда, какая - нужно смотреть под отладчиком